# Nodejs event on page exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am very new to NodeJS and ExpressJS, but was wondering if there is an event that fires when a page is left. I have an ExpressJS/NodeJS application, and in the app.js i set up a UDP listener on a particular page; i.e.

```
app.get('/sims', function(req, res) {

    var udp = require('dgram');
    var udpSocket = udp.createSocket('udp4');
    udpSocket.bind(8081);

    udpSocket.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("server error:\n" + err.stack);
        udpSocket.close();
    });

    udpSocket.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
        console.log("server got: " + msg + " from " +
              rinfo.address + ":" + rinfo.port);
        //do stuff with the message to dynamically update the page
    });

    udpSocket.on("listening", function () {
        var address = udpSocket.address();
        console.log("server listening " +
             address.address + ":" + address.port);
    });

    udpSocket.on("close", function () {
        console.log("udp socket closed!!!");
    });
});
```

My question is, how do i know when to close the udpSocket? I can't close it within the scope of the app.get, and it doesnt seem to automatically close when i leave the page. I dont want to just leave a bunch of UDP sockets open everytime someone visits the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: HTTP is not bidirectional, so there is only one "way" to send data (server to client).

So i think you either add a timeout mechanism (close socket if no message was sent in time X) or look at websockets (which allow bidirectional communication). I suggest looking at socket.io, Primus, Engine.io or google "node websocket" ;)

Comment: Ok; i think in the context of my application, i may actually have the server send a "completed" message of some sort, rather than a timeout mechanism. This will allow the client to know that it is done dynamically updating and can close the socket. Thanks!